# How do I align Radio Buttons center in LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, radio-button, android-linearlayout

How do I center align Radio button inside `LinearLayout`

**For the TextViews:**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.4">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="Often"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:text="Sometimes"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Rarely"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="Never"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

**For the RadioButtons:**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.4">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:padding="2dp"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:padding="2dp"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

This is still it looks like :

[image]

May I know where i am doing mistake, I already tried with `layout_gravity = "center"` and `gravity = "center"`

How can i align it to Center, where i have to make change ?

Comment: where are you setting the text ?

Comment: Your textviews and radio buttons are in different layouts i guess.

Comment: may i know from where are you setting your textviews

Comment: give same weight which you are giving int the textview layout

Comment: post you layout of textview also

Comment: Please provide the rest of your XML

Comment: i am using everything same for textviews even they are not center aligned, in place of RadioButtons i am using TextViews that's it...

Comment: check i posted textviews xml as well, even not able to align TextViews center

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to do..i suggest you the below layout..

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one. It will work for no of buttons you want.
Surely its works:

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Often"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Sometimes"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Rarely"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Never"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Often"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Sometimes"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Rarely"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Never"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: i don't have only 4 radio buttons in a line, i have 10 lines of radio buttons

Comment: In this layout you can put your no of buttons. It will work for all.

Answer (score 0):

Check this It will make both checkbox and textview in center.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Often"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Often"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Often"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Often"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: PIC]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line in the radio button's block which you want to align at the center:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```